# table joining to get output

Tags: php, mysql, inner-join

I am trying to get a result by joining two tables . but i am not getting proper result . can any one tell where i am wrong ?

here is my code

```
$sql = "SELECT merchant.name, keyword.name
FROM keyword 
INNER JOIN merchant
ON merchant.id=keyword.merchant_id";
```

And my table structurer is

**keyword**

1.name (keyword name)

2.merchant_id

**merchant**

1.id

2.name (merchant name)

the result sholud be like this

**merchant name |||||| keyword name**

and SQL fetch query is

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($retval, MYSQL_ASSOC)) 
{

  echo "<tr><td>".$row['name']."</td><td>".$row['name']."</td>";

 }
```

But the output is

**keyword name |||||| keyword name**

[image]

only i am getting keyword name

can any one tell me where i am wrong . (sorry for my bad English)

Comment: echo "<tr><td>".$row['name']."</td><td>".$row['name']."</td>"; both are same variable

Comment: again dont use `mysql_` functions... they are deprecated

Comment: need change variable name ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dont use [mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13944956/the-mysql-extension-is-deprecated-and-will-be-removed-in-the-future-use-mysqli) use Mysqli

you could try

```
$sql = "SELECT merchant.name as mname, keyword.name as kname FROM keyword INNER JOIN merchant  ON merchant.id=keyword.merchant_id";
```

and

```
echo "<tr><td>".$row['mname']."</td><td>".$row['kname']."</td>";
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$sql = "SELECT merchant.name as m_name, keyword.name as a_name
    FROM keyword 
    INNER JOIN merchant
    ON merchant.id=keyword.merchant_id";
```

Then

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($retval, MYSQL_ASSOC)) 
{

  echo "<tr><td>".$row['m_name']."</td><td>".$row['a_name']."</td>";

 }
```

Comment: this also help full :)

Answer (score 1):

The issue arises because you are having two column in the query with same name and second one overrides first. Try this:

```
$sql = "SELECT merchant.name as mer_name, keyword.name as k_name  // Aliasing for column names
FROM keyword 
INNER JOIN merchant
ON merchant.id=keyword.merchant_id";
```

and use it like:

```
$row['mer_name'], $row['k_name'];
```